# Polymorphism using Interface and Classes

Tags: java, polymorphism

Is there any difference on the polymorphism coded below? Basically is there difference in the binding of the method calls?

Polymorphism Type 1:

```
class A
{
    public void method()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void method()
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Now I do stuff with B using A

```
A a =  new B();
a.method();
```

Polymorphism type 2:

```
public interface Command
{
    public void execute();
}

public class ReadCommand implements Command
{
    public void execute()
    {
        //do reading stuff
    }
}

public class WriteCommand implements Command
{
    public void execute()
    {
        //do writing stuff
    }
}

public class CommandFactory
{
    public static Command getCommand(String s)
    {
        if(s.equals("Read"))
        {
            return new ReadCommand();
        }
        if(s.equals("Write"))
        {
            return new WriteCommand();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I use the command factory:

```
Command c = CommandFactory.getCommand("Read");
c.execute();
```

My question is : Is there any difference in the above two polymorphisms. I know both are examples of run time polymorphism, but is there any difference [with respect to binding of the methods], or any other difference for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there's one difference between

```
Command c = CommandFactory.getCommand("Read");
```

and

```
A a =  new B();
```

... in the first case, you have *no option* but to use the interface (or just `Object`) because the expression on right hand side of the assignment operator is of type `Command`.

In the second case, you're deliberately *choosing* to assign the result to a variable of type `A`, even though you *could* have written

```
B b = new B();
```

This is really just a difference in the design choices though - it doesn't affect how a call to `c.execute()` or `a.execute()` will actually behave.

Comment: @Swaranga: Given that it's to do with Google interviews, I think I'd better not comment any further to be honest...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Polymorphism Type 1` and `Polymorphism Type 2` is the same polymorphism :)

Answer (score 0):

With respect to **runtime** behavior there is **no different**. But

The difference is with the **compilation**. ie

In 1st Type as you are using the direct class references you need both the classes to be present at the compile time.

But With 2nd type the classes are required only at the runtime.

Comment: No, the `CommandFactory` of the second type needs `ReadCommand` as well as `WriteCommand` at compile time and eventually at runtime.

Comment: If you have compiled the CommandFactory separately and added it into the jar, which this code has in its classpath, then its not required to have in compile time.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in binding (runtime). Type 1 is tightly coupled whereas type 2 is loosely coupled, makes a difference in compiling.

Answer (score 0):

As a user, for Type 2 you will not require implementations of the interface to be included/imported. Means you just order instance of any implementation without knowing/including/importing that implementation itself.

For Type 1, you need to include/import each implementation in case you have to use that implementation.